# Object-relational mapping (ORM)

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent, orm, laravel-9

What is Object-relational mapping (ORM) give ans in simple language with example?

Try to understand what is Object-relational mapping (ORM)

Answer (score 0):

ORM- Object Relational Mapping is a tool which allows database row to refer as object in PHP programming.  What Wikipedia says about ORM is:

> Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping) in computer
> software is a programming technique for converting data between
> incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming languages.
> This creates, in effect, a “virtual object database” that can be used
> from within the programming language.

(Object-Relational Mapping) is a tool that allows you query database table and manipulate data from a database using an object paradigm (Object Oriented).

Briefly, ORM give you possibilities about write short, clean, relational by many SQL/NoSQL languages in one type of code:

Example by Laravel and pure SQL.

Without ORM:

```sql
 Select * from cities where exists (Select * from countries where cities.country_id = countries.id and id > 10)
```

With ORM (after relation):

```php
$cities = Cities::with('countries')->get();
```